# Using random numbers to determine the length of a random number list

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate a list of random odd numbers in a specific range with the length of the list generated by calling another random number in PYTHON (and then writing them to a file).

I've been able to generate the initial random number (and threw in a display caller to see what it was).  When I try to use it as the length of the list of the other of randomly generated numbers it doesn't work. I'm not certain why. Any insight would be appreciated. Here's what I've got...

```
import random 

def main():
    digit_file = open("numbers.txt","w")
    file_size = random.randint(4,7)
    print (file_size)
    print ("is the file size\n" )
    for n in range(file_size): 
        rand_output = random.randint(5,19)
        if n %2 != 0:
            print(rand_output)
            digit_file.write(str(rand_output))
    digit_file.close
    print("File was created and closed.")
main()
```

Comment: What's the problem? The code works. Also don't forget to use parenthesis in  `digit_file.close()`

Comment: @FadingCaptain How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: The amount of numbers generated by rand_output doesn't equal file_size.

Comment: @FadingCaptain, it's because you use `if n%2 != 0`, that means that not all numbers will be written.

Comment: You're right. I guess I'll have to find another way to keep the numbers odd but still generate the same amount as file_size

Comment: You may use `2 * random.randint(2, 9) + 1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what you expect but what about using `choice` ?

```
from random import randint,choice

def main():
    with open("numbers.txt","w") as digit_file:
        file_size = randint(4,7)
        print (file_size)
        print ("is the file size\n" )
        for n in range(file_size): 
            rand_output = choice(range(5, 19, 2))
            print(rand_output)
            digit_file.write(str(rand_output))
    print("File was created and closed.")

main()
```

That can become :

```
from random import randint,choice

def main():
    with open("numbers.txt","w") as f:
        file_size = randint(4,7)
        print ("%dis the file size\n" % file_size)
        f.write(''.join(str(choice(range(5, 19, 2))) for _ in range(file_size)))
    print("File was created and closed.")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `rand_output % 2 != 0` not `n % 2 != 0` :

```
import random


def main():
    digit_file = open("numbers.txt", "w")
    file_size = random.randint(4, 7)
    print(file_size)
    print("is the file size\n")
    while file_size:
        rand_output = random.randint(5, 19)
        if rand_output % 2 != 0:
            print(rand_output)
            digit_file.write(str(rand_output))
            file_size -= 1
    digit_file.close()
    print("File was created and closed.")
main()
```

Comment: I tried that but the file_size number generated was 7 and the number of digits generated by rand_output was 5.

Comment: @FadingCaptain, I understood you wrong first time. I've updated my answer

Comment: Brilliant! I'm new to programming and didn't remember to make rand_output dependent on file_size.  Why is it necessary to subtract 1 from file_size at the end?

Comment: @FadingCaptain, It was your problem, your `rand_output` depended on size, but it's not correct. The ideas is that you don't need to make `file_size` iterations, you need to make more, as sometimes a number will be even and you will have to do additional iteration. Now we do iteration while `file_size != 0`, and each time we found an odd number we `file_size -= 1`. This means that 'iteration' is done only if the number is odd.